# Writing text file with python with merge line operator "\"

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I am trying to automate a script in python to write the following command with it's options. I was able to do the following

```
foo -1 \ 
    -2 a \ 
    -3 b \ 
    -4 c \ 
    -5 d \ 
    -6 e \ 
    -7 f
```

Which seems right. However, when I use bash to source the file that contains this in a terminal, it complains that it does not have any options specified and bash doesn't recognize `-2`, `-3`, `-4`, `-5` etc. How can I write this properly to ensure that when the file is being sourced, it'll read it right?

Code:

```
filehandle.write("foo\t-1 \ \n") 
filehandle.write("-2 a \ \n") 
filehandle.write("-3 b \ \n") 
filehandle.write("-4 c \ \n") 
filehandle.write("-5 d \ \n") 
filehandle.write("-6 e \ \n") 
filehandle.write("-7 f \ \n")
```

Comment: How is this related to Python?

Comment: Because I'm writing it with python.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "sourcing" this file? Python can't source files, but BASH can, with the `source` command. What Python code are you using to run this command?

Comment: Python is writing this file. Then I go in bash to source the .txt file that contains the command. However, bash is not seeing it as one entire command but as many.

Comment: Notice there are trailing spaces after your `\` in the output you generate. This tells bash to escape the *space* character, not the newline character that follows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by specifying that each new line with the arguments should start with `\t`:

```
>>> with open("test.sh", "w") as f:
...   f.write("ls \\\n\t-l\\\n\t-h\n")
... 
14
>>>
```

Also, there mustn't be any spaces after the backslash that terminates each line, so this: `"foo\t-1 \ \n"` should become this: `"foo\t-1 \\\n"` (spaces *before* the backslash are fine).

Also note that this: `"\\n"` will write to the file literally `backslash, "n"` because the first backslash escapes the `\n` symbol, so you have to escape that first backslash with `"\\\n"`.

So the file looks like this:

```
$ cat test.sh
ls \
    -l\
    -h
$
```

Comment: Thank you, the tripled backslash is what I was missing. I don't think I can give you the rep points now, but I will as soon as it lets me. Thank you

Comment: Tabs aren't necessary, any whitespace will do. The key point is that there can't be any whitespace between the backslash and the newline in the output.